# Stored procedure returns incorrect values

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

My query returns correct values , but when i run the query as a stored procedure it returns incorrect results. this is my query which returns correct values

```
select 
    imageId, imageVerified, isCoverImage, isDeleted, isProfileImage,
    path, profileId
from 
    images  
where 
    profileId = 5;
```

When I run this stored procedure, it is returning all rows and shows profileId as the passed in profileId.

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getImagesForUser`(in profileId long)
BEGIN
    select imageId,imageVerified,isCoverImage,isDeleted,isProfileImage,path,profileId
    from images  where profileId = profileId;
END
```

This is how I call this procedure:

```
CALL `tfm`.`getImagesForUser`(5);
```

Please see the screenshots

Screenshot for query:

[image: screenshot for query]

This is the incorrect result from stored procedure:

[image: incorrect result from stored procedure]

You can see, mysql says all the images belongs to profileId 5 , which I passed in.

What is wrong with my stored procedure?

Comment: you're creating an SP `getImagesForUser` but you're calling one called `getAllImagesForUser`, is that a typo?

Comment: sorry that was a typo, `getAllImagesForUser` was the original one and i dropped it and created `getImagesForUser`. I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your input parameter has the same name as the field in your table, and inside your query MySQL interprets `profileId` as being the field name instead. Thus your `where profileId = profileId` is always true, and you get all rows. Change the name of the input parameter e.g.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getImagesForUser`(in searchProfileId long)
BEGIN
    select imageId,imageVerified,isCoverImage,isDeleted,isProfileImage,path,profileId
    from images  where profileId = searchProfileId;
END
```